# Data Tool for SSRS not installed correctly

Tags: reporting-services

Can anybody help me that how can I installed Data Tool for SSRS correctly. During installation it is not able to located BI while I already installed BI with SQL SERVER.

Due to incomplete installation I am unable to select MS dynamic CRM Fetch from DataSource dropdown.

Window - 8,
SQL Server 2012,
VS 2012

Thank!

Jahangir

Answer (score 0):

While installing SSMS along with BI  we will get the following services to select to install,

1. Management tools-Basic
2. Integration services
3. Reporting Services
4. Analysis Services

We need to select all above options to work on BI with SQL.

I hope this will help you

Thanks
Venky